# Understanding the meaning of the two below expressions related to rate change

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity

We know that velocity vector $\vec{v}$ is given by $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of a particle carrying a 2D motion . I would like to know what then $\frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}$, $|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}|$ would mean ?

> what i think that for first one taking modulus of position vector will tell the magnitude from origin so that quantity is rate of change of magntiude of position vector but i dont get what it can be equal to .

- For the second one i can think of it like taking the magnitude part of the rate of change of position vector so it might mean speed since velocity is speed with a unit vector direction ? That is $\vec{v}$ velocity = $v(speed) * \hat{n}$ ? Where is n is a unit vector ? Am i right ?

Comment: Hint: Consider for example a uniform circular motion to see the difference and meaning of these quantities.

Comment: Hmm , so first one would have constant value of zero since magnirude is not changing of position vector am i right ? And second one would be speed v ?but i would like to know in general not for these special cases :(

Comment: It is kinda self explanatory. The second one is simply the module of velocity, that you can see as the length of the velocit vector. The first one, $\frac{d |v|}{dt}$ is the change of the length of the velocity vector.

Comment: See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711987/83835) and the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know what then $\frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}$, $|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}|$ would mean ?

In two dimensions $|\vec r| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. So, to find $\frac{d|\vec r|}{dt}$ use the product rule and chain rule:
$$
\frac{d|\vec r|}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{-1/2}\left(2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{|\vec r|}\left(\vec r\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}\right)
$$

This is the rate of change of the magnitude of the $\vec r$ vector (by definition).

---

You can use similar definitions to find an expression for $|\frac{d\vec r}{dt}|$, which is the magnitude of the rate of change of the $\vec r$ vector. (As opposed to the rate of change of the magnitude of the $\vec r$ vector, discussed above the line.)